# Socket IO private message with room dosen't work

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, socket.io, react-hooks

I'm doing a Tinder Web app, and I want to implement real-time chat. I use ReactJS for clients and Nodejs for the server, I add Socket.IO for the chat app.

When 2 profiles matched each other then they can talk together, so when they match I create a room for them with a unique id create from their user_id. So let's imagine :

User_id 90  match with user_id 50 generateRoomid(90, 50) created.

Server-side there is 3 event, the connection event, the create_room event, and chat-message event.

```
 io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("user_connected", (user_id) => {

  /* when they log in I store socket.id but it change every time so I will delete it */

   addUser({socket_id: socket.id, user_id: user_id})
  })

  socket.on("create_room", (data, cookie) => {
   let decode = jwt.verify(cookie, process.env.JWT_SECRET)
   let user_id = decode.id
   let total_match_id = data.map(a => a.id);

   /* when user log I catch all match he has and create room for each match */

   total_match_id.forEach((id) => {
     let room_id = GenerateRoom(user_id, id)
     socket.join(room_id)
    })

 })

 socket.on("chat-message", ({ message, user_send, user_receive }) => {
   var fullDate = getFullDate();
   let room_id = GenerateRoom(user_send, user_receive)
   io.to(room_id).emit("chat-message", { user_send, user_receive, message, fullDate })
   insertMessage(user_send, user_receive, message, fullDate)
 })
});
```

Client-side I do 2 things, a form that send/emit the message, and a defect that wait for the response to display it :

```
  /* useEffect */

  const socketMessage = async () => {
  socket.on("chat-message", (data) => {
    setAllMessage(allMessage => [...allMessage, data.message ]);
  });
  socketMessage(
  
  //
  
 /* onSubmit */
const sendMessage = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const user_send = user.id
  const user_receive = userChat.id
  if (message !== "" && message != null) {
   socket.emit("chat-message", { user_send, message, user_receive });
   setMessage("");
  }
}
```

Before I wanted to use socket.id but the thing is the socket.id change for each page, it's normal I know but I can't store it, so after reading Socket.io doc, rooms was the best choice for me, I follow documentation but it doesn't work, it works when I emit to all client (io.emit) but when I try to emit on a room it doesn't work.

Any idea? What did I do wrong?

Comment: You have issue with socket.emit("chat-message", { user_send, message, user_receive }); on client side please swap parameters
socket.emit("chat-message", { message, user_send, , user_receive });

Comment: still same, and when i emit even if parameters are not same place it changes nothing because its an object

Comment: I have full chat app in jQuery && express and all works perfect,when i m trying to rewrite client side in react all works except private messages and i m struggling many days.Cant figure out why this happen.